# Random crashes on elementary OS

Tags: fedora, system-installation, elementary-os, crash

I've been trying different distros on my laptop because I'd really like to switch to Linux but I can't seem to make it work.

I installed Fedora and [elementary OS](http://elementaryos.org/) (which worked before) on my laptop and after a whole day of installing both of them crash randomly. elementary OS crashed during installation few times and the only thing I saw was a block of text from where I only understood that the process is `install.py` and it said Bad RIP value.

Once I managed to install elementary OS I tried updating it and then it crashed again, this time the process was `dpkg` and again, Bad RIP value.

The laptop is Acer Aspire 5741G (latest BIOS and VGA BIOS) with i5 430M, 3GB of DDR3 and HD5470 512MB.

Comment: *Bad RIP value* -> this [can be debugged](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/crash-analyze.html) I think but it is not easy, and it may be a hardware issue.  The application that seems to trigger it is probably not important, since it is a failure within the kernel.  How old is the laptop?  Does anything else (e.g windows) currently run OK on it?

Comment: @goldilocks Laptop is a few years old but both Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 work fine on it (no crashes). I did try doing an upgrade with wired connection and it hasn't crashed so now I'm installing Broadcom drivers from Additional drivers to see if that works!